# How do I bypass the "SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop" so that I can break the last loop and end the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner to programming and this is my first question here, please do help me!
How do I bypass the

```
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

in line 33 & 41 so that I can break the last loop and end the code? I mean I could just make the both if statements at the last loop but I want to keep things organized for maybe future codes.

```
# Configures Hero class
class Hero():
    def __init__(self, name, hp, atk, defence):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.atk = atk
        self.defence = defence

    def attackAction(self, enemy):
        print(self.name + " attacks " + enemy.name + "!")
        enemy.defenceAction(self, self.atk)

    def defenceAction(self, enemy, atk_enemy):
        print(self.name + " defenced against " + enemy.name + "'s attack.")
        calculatedAtk = abs(atk_enemy/self.defence)
        self.hp -= calculatedAtk
        print(self.name + " lost " + str(calculatedAtk) + "HP!")
        print(self.name + " now has " + str(self.hp) + " remaining.")



#Archer and Wizard attributes
archer = Hero("Archer", 20, 2, 2)
wizard = Hero("Wizard", 15, 3, 1)

# Checks Wizard's HP
def checkWizHP():
    if wizard.hp <= 0:
        print(wizard.name + " has died.")
        print("Archer has won!")
        game_on = False
        break

# Checks Archer's HP
def checkArchHP():
    if archer.hp <= 0:
        print(archer.name + " has died.")
        print("Wizard has won!")
        game_on = False
        break

# Checks winning condition
def checkWin():
    checkWizHP()
    checkArchHP()

game_on = True

while game_on:
    archer.attackAction(wizard)
    print("\n")
    checkWin()
    wizard.attackAction(archer)
    checkWin()
```

Comment: You don't have a loop but you're using ```break```. Remove that break

Comment: ```break``` is used to come out of a loop. To come out of a function you have to use ```return```. By the way you don't need any of these in your functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "end the code"? Exiting from the function or from the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `False` or `True`. If `True` is returned, you can break. This will change your code to:

```
# Checks Wizard's HP
def checkWizHP():
    if wizard.hp <= 0:
        print(wizard.name + " has died.")
        print("Archer has won!")
        game_on = False
        return False
    return True


# Checks Archer's HP
def checkArchHP():
    if archer.hp <= 0:
        print(archer.name + " has died.")
        print("Wizard has won!")
        game_on = False
        return False
    return True

# Checks winning condition
def checkWin():
    return checkWizHP() and checkArchHP()

while game_on:
    archer.attackAction(wizard)
    print("\n")
    if not checkWin():
        break
    wizard.attackAction(archer)
    if not checkWin():
        break
```

I also see that you are setting `game_on` in your functions. To be able to set a global variable, you need to add `global game_on` in your function. Then you can use `game_on` to check if you are done, which is more flexible.

```
# Checks Wizard's HP
def checkWizHP():
    global game_on
    if wizard.hp <= 0:
        print(wizard.name + " has died.")
        print("Archer has won!")
        game_on = False

# Checks Archer's HP
def checkArchHP():
    global game_on
    if archer.hp <= 0:
        print(archer.name + " has died.")
        print("Wizard has won!")
        game_on = False



while game_on:
    archer.attackAction(wizard)
    print("\n")
    checkWin():
    if not game_on:
        break
    wizard.attackAction(archer)
    checkWin():
    if not game_on:
        break
```

In this example, only this code will change, all other code will remain the same

Comment: No semi-colon after ```break```!

Comment: Agree with that: OP designed the code so that the game ends while `game_on`, so setting `game_on=False` is the way to end the game.

Comment: @Sujay sorry, used to semi-colons and braces! FIxed now

Comment: Using a global is generally bad style, although that just could be the way the question is written; if this is inside a class, setting `self.game_on = False` would be fine

Comment: Thanks man, this really helped me fix my code, I never knew I could use the return function to set it that way. Also, I set ```game_on = False```

Comment: yeah, I completely agree. The only reason I had that is because they had a variable like that

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a `break` statement has to be within the physical body of the loop; it can't be in a function that's called from a loop

Two options how to do this:

- Return `True` or `False` from the functions and use that to break out of the loop at the top level.

  ```
   def checkWizHP():
       if wizard.hp <= 0:
           print(wizard.name + " has died.")
           print("Archer has won!")
           return True
       else:
           return False

   def checkWin():
       return checkWizHP() or checkArchHP()

   ...

   while True:
       ...
       if checkWin():
           break
       ...
  ```
- Raise an exception then catch it.

  ```
   class GameEnd(Exception):
       pass

   def checkWizHP():
       if wizard.hp <= 0:
           print(wizard.name + " has died.")
           print("Archer has won!")
           raise GameEnd("Archer has won!")

   def checkWin():
       checkWizHP()
       checkArchHP()

   ...

   try:
       while True:
           ...
           checkWin()
           ...
   except GameEnd:
       print("game finished")
  ```

Which one to use is a matter of style; in a simple game as you've posted, the "return `True` or `False`" option is clearer. In more complex situations, either may be more straightforward; it depends on how much of the code directly interacts with the win / game end conditions, compared to how much would be just passing it along, complicating the explicit logic in that part.

Comment: Returning True or False is better that to raise an catch an exception

Comment: It depends on the situation; either can be clearer. I'll add a bit of discussion to my answer...

Comment: @sabik also the `else` is quite redundant since you return so it can return only one value anyways

Comment: Yeah, that's a style question; "omit redundant else" vs "symmetry of branches"